# A small definition question on Poisson random measure

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Assume $(S,\mathcal{S},\eta)$ is an arbitrary $\sigma$-finite measure space. Let $N:\mathcal S\rightarrow\{0,1,2,\ldots\}\cup\{\infty\}$ in a way such that $\{N(A):A\in\mathcal S\}$ are random variables defined on the probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$. Then $N$ is called a Poisson random measure on  $(S,\mathcal{S},\eta)$ if

(i) for mutually disjoint $A_1,\ldots,A_n$ in $\mathcal{S}$, the variables $N(A_i),\ldots,N(A_n)$ are independent,

(ii) for each $A\in\mathcal{S}$, $N(A)$ is Poisson variable distributed with parameter $\eta(A)$.

(iii) $\mathbb{P}$-almost surely, $N$ is a measure.

I don't quite understand what (iii) means.

In the context of a Levy process, I can see that $\eta$ corresponds to the product measure of the jump measure in a Levy process and Lebesgue measure on $t$, and ($S$, $\mathcal{S}$) is the measure space generated by the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}\times[0,\infty)$.

Comment: Since $N$ is a function on $\Omega \times \mathcal{S}$, we may fix $\omega \in \Omega$ and observe how the mapping $E \mapsto N(\omega, E)$ behaves. In particular, we can consider a set $$ \{ \omega \in \Omega : E \mapsto N(\omega, E) \text{ is a measure on } S \}.$$ The condition (iii) then implies that this set is an event with probability 1.

Comment: @sos440 get it, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am writing out sos's answer so that this question can be marked as answered.

$N$ is a function on $\Omega\times \mathcal{S}$. Fix $\omega\in\Omega$ and consider the mapping $E\rightarrow N(\omega,E)$.

The set $\{\omega\in\Omega : E\rightarrow N(\omega,E) \text{ is a measure on S}\}$ is an event with probability 1.